# Unable to Detect Serial Ports on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) when Deploying Node.js App

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, serial-port, iot, esp32

I have developed a Node.js application that reads data from sensors connected to serial ports. The app works fine locally, but when I deploy it on Google Cloud Platform (GCP), it is unable to detect the serial ports on the laptop.

I am utilizing the 'serialport' library to retrieve a list of serial ports and establish a connection to the serial port of the board. Is there any solution to connect these serial ports to my project on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why detecting serial ports between Google Cloud Platform and your laptop is due to the nature of cloud environments, where direct access to hardware components such as serial ports, etc. were restricted for security and isolation reasons.

You can try Serial Port Forwarding with SSH Tunneling to have direct access to the serial ports of your local machine. There is Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) with Serial Port Emulation that you can consider for more flexibility and avoids the need for SSH tunneling.